# Creating a combo chart with bar and data icons

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, icons

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I'd like to create a chart like so:

[image]

My data source is a pivot table with 3 columns - `Category`, `Revenue` and `Growth` (a calculated field).

I'm thinking of a combo chart with one series as a column (`Revenue`) and the other just the text with some conditional formatting (data icons and color).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little trickery...

Here's a snapshot of the data and the chart I set up as an example:

[image]

You need to do a few things, and it will take some back-and-forth to get it just right.

1. Turn off the border of the chart: Border Color set to "No Line"
2. Chart position and column size...

   - Position the chart **and** resize the columns behind it so that the bars are as close to centered in the column as possible.
   - Also set the columns either side of the chart (columns "E" and "I" in this example) so that their edges are just beyond the left/right edges of the chart.

[image]

3. Now, in the cells immediately on top of the chart, enter the data/formula that gets you the value you need. In my case, it's `=SUMIF(Table1[Category],"A",Table1[Growth])`. Now you get:

[image]

4. Apply some conditional formatting for the values...

[image]

5. And finally, set the fill color of the background cells surrounding the chart to white (or the background color of your chart) and set a colored border in the closest cells. I left an extra row above mine to set a title.

[image]